Why use a dynamic library when only a single application will use it
I understand generally how dynamic static libraries work.
But i don't understand why a lot of libraries online will recommend building them to be dynamic, or why some programs like Unity ship with over 30 DLL's alongside it's main EXE file.
To my understanding, the main benefit of dynamic libraries (.DLL/.so), is that multiple programs can use the same piece of code in memory at the same time. However often this is not the case, as mentioned with Unity, that comes with over 30 DLL's that only it uses.
And i could imagine this affects startup time as a lot of functions have to be loaded at runtime before Unity can work.
Final question:
Should i consider using dynamic libraries for a program or app, even if said libraries will only be used by my program, and why?
(Bonus question) And why do some applications (like Unity) ship with a bunch of .DLL's instead of Linking staticly, avoiding the downsides.

The key benefits of a dynamic library these days are pretty much either no longer compelling, or are irrelevant.  In theory, if there is a bug in a DLL, you could just ship a fixed DLL -- that'd be the last big benefit.  (They're still useful for plugins.  Or for not often needed functionality that can be loaded on demand to make for a smaller in memory working set.  Or for architecture specific DLL selection, such as loading bottleneck routines DLL one being a SSE3 optimized DLL or a AVX512 optimized DLL.)

One other benefit is that you don't necessarily have to rebuild an entire large project if you make some change to the DLL-housed code. Although given the realities of modern systems it would have to be an extremely large project where this actually becomes an issue.

Dynamic libraries don't have to be loaded at startup. They can be loaded by the application when they're first needed, which, of corse, means that if they're not needed (because of what the current run of the application is doing) they don't get loaded at all, saving memory.
